# Micro QR-code reading solution

Tags: integrated-circuit, bluetooth, diy

I've tried to repair a headset, but I cannot identify the chipset because they used something that looked like QR code but smaller (wikipedia states that it's micro QR) and I have no solution to read it (cheap if possible, but i can spend money for quality).[image: the U1 part]

Comment: So what's your question that fits the mission of this site?

Comment: If you want help reading a micro-QR code, best put a picture so we know how to advise you.

Comment: I added the picture @jonathanjo

Comment: @Transistor my Question is : how can I replace the U1 unit ? I try to understand how and why the bluetooth part of the headset "died" (the owner said that he plugged his headset and then the bluetooth stopped working, so that look like a short-circuit, I have a multimeter to start probbing). 

I'm studying mechatronics at the university but never had the opportunity to design PCB (we did automation, signals processing and so on...)

the U1 look like a micro-controller ( as there's a lot of capacitors + the quartz near him) but the part under the quartz is also one. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

The "QR" code is actually [Data Matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Matrix) (QR codes have "eyes", DM codes have "solid L and dotted L" along the edges).  To decode it, you can just put the image into the [ZX decoding](https://zxing.org) website, which says the code reads "**257202010448**".  It is most likely to be some internal code of the board manufacturer.

Manufacturers normally only label custom parts or programmed parts such as ROMs, microcontrollers, FPGAs etc, and so are very rarely replaceable without a spare from the manufacturer.

> Raw bytes: 9b ca 84 83 86 b2 81 38
>   Barcode format: DATA_MATRIX
>   Parsed Result Type: TEXT
>   Parsed Result: 257202010448

Comment: Ah ! well Thanks a lot ... I tried to contact the Community Manager of the compagny ( Focal) but they said that they won't share such infos.

@jonathanjo : how do I found out about the board manufacturer ( I do not own the circuit so I have to ask/"move" to look for infos on it)